# Sum, series and Harmonic numbers

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, harmonic-analysis, harmonic-numbers

I found the solution of series on Wolfram Alpha http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+1%2F(2k%2B1)%2F(2k%2B2)+from+1+to+n%2F2

for $\alpha = 1$

$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n/2} \left(\frac{1}{\left(2k-1+2^{1/\alpha}\right)^\alpha} - \frac{1}{\left(2k+2^{1/\alpha}\right)^\alpha}\right)=\frac{1}{2} \left(-H_{\frac{n}{2}+1} + H_\frac{n+1}{2} -1 + \text{ln}(4)\right)$

Can someone tell how to prove this in the form of Harmonic numbers?

Comment: If you found my answer below useful, will you please accept it (clicking the arrow). Stack exchange sites only survive through people donating their time to help each other. If the answer is not clear, then feel free to ask for clarification in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler expression, can be obtained via direct calculation. This avoids introducing irrational terms (such as $\log(4)$ in the solution from Wolfram Alpha).

Assuming $n$ is even (else the summation you provide is not defined), for $\alpha = 1$ the summation is equivalent to

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{n/2} \left( \frac{1}{2k+1} - \frac{1}{2(k+1)} \right) & =
\sum_{k=1}^{n/2} \frac{1}{2k+1} - \frac12 \sum_{k=1}^{n/2} \frac{1}{k+1}\\
 & = \sum_{k=1}^{n/2} \frac{1}{2k+1} - \frac12 \big(H_{n/2 +1} - 1 \big)\\
& = \sum_{k=1}^{n/2} \left( \frac{1}{2k+1}  + \frac{1}{2k} - \frac{1}{2k} \right) - \frac12 \big(H_{n/2 +1} - 1 \big) \\
& = \sum_{k=1}^{n/2} \left( \frac{1}{2k+1}  + \frac{1}{2k}\right) - \sum_{k=1}^{n/2} \frac{1}{2k}- \frac12 \big(H_{n/2 +1} - 1 \big) \\
& = \sum_{k=1}^{n/2} \left( \frac{1}{2k+1}  + \frac{1}{2k}\right) - \frac12\sum_{k=1}^{n/2} \frac{1}{k}- \frac12 \big(H_{n/2 +1} - 1 \big) \\
& = \sum_{k=1}^{n/2} \left( \frac{1}{2k+1}  + \frac{1}{2k}\right) - \frac12 H_{n/2} - \frac12 \big(H_{n/2 +1} - 1 \big) \\
& = \sum_{k=2}^{n+1} \frac1k  - \frac12 H_{n/2}- \frac12 \big(H_{n/2 +1} - 1 \big) \\
& = (H_{n+1} -1)  - \frac12 H_{n/2} - \frac12 \big(H_{n/2 +1} - 1 \big) \\
& =H_{n+1} - \frac12 \left(H_{n/2} + H_{n/2 + 1}-1 \right)
\end{align*}

---

To test the answer, consider the arbitrary case $n = 16$

Left hand side.
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+1%2F(+(2k%2B1)++(2k%2B2)+)+from+1+to+8

Right hand side.
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=H(n%2B1)+-1+-+1%2F2+H(n%2F2)+-+1%2F2+(H(n%2F2+%2B1)+-1)+with+n+%3D+16&rawformassumption=%7B%22FunClash%22,+%22H%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22HarmonicNumber%22%7D